Nvidia driver 545 suddenly stopped working for Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS
All of a sudden the driver for my Nvidia 4080 stopped working. I don't recall changing anything but the next day I was greeted with a log-in screen that had a tiny resolution and it didn't recognise the second screen. This was due to the graphics driver (version 545.29.06) not working anymore and I am very confused as to why that is. I try to provide as much pertinent information as I can, please correct me if I miss anything.
Currently I had to re-install version 535.183.01 but unfortunately the performance of this driver is noticeably slower (e.g. in playing video games I get a lot of frame drops) that this is not a solution.
Below I outline every step I took to get a newer version than 535 installed again but each failed.
TLDR: Does anyone have any advice what issue I am facing here and how it can be solved? How can I install a newer driver?
Installing a driver other than 535 fails
In general, I only have these relatively old drivers available, which I also wonder about:
sudo ubuntu-drivers list

Output:
nvidia-driver-535-server, (kernel modules provided by linux-modules-nvidia-535-server-generic-hwe-22.04)
nvidia-driver-535-open, (kernel modules provided by linux-modules-nvidia-535-open-generic-hwe-22.04)
nvidia-driver-545-open, (kernel modules provided by nvidia-dkms-545-open)
nvidia-driver-545, (kernel modules provided by nvidia-dkms-545)
nvidia-driver-535-server-open, (kernel modules provided by linux-modules-nvidia-535-server-open-generic-hwe-22.04)
nvidia-driver-535, (kernel modules provided by linux-modules-nvidia-535-generic-hwe-22.04)


When I try to install, a 545 driver again, I get the following error message:
sudo ubuntu-drivers install nvidia:545

The end of the output:
ERROR: Cannot create report: [Errno 17] File exists: '/var/crash/nvidia-dkms-545.0.crash'
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 6.8.0-40-generic (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/nvidia/545.29.06/build/make.log for more information.
dpkg: error processing package nvidia-dkms-545 (--configure):
 installed nvidia-dkms-545 package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 10
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of nvidia-driver-545:
 nvidia-driver-545 depends on nvidia-dkms-545 (<= 545.29.06-1); however:
  Package nvidia-dkms-545 is not configured yet.
 nvidia-driver-545 depends on nvidia-dkms-545 (>= 545.29.06); however:
  Package nvidia-dkms-545 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package nvidia-driver-545 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                                                                          Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.35-0ubuntu3.8) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.10.2-1) ...
Processing triggers for initramfs-tools (0.140ubuntu13.4) ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-6.8.0-40-generic
Errors were encountered while processing:
 nvidia-dkms-545
 nvidia-driver-545
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

Running
sudo apt install nvidia-driver-545

Produces this output:
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 6.8.0-40-generic (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/nvidia/545.29.06/build/make.log for more information.
dpkg: error processing package nvidia-dkms-545 (--configure):
 installed nvidia-dkms-545 package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 10
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of nvidia-driver-545:
 nvidia-driver-545 depends on nvidia-dkms-545 (<= 545.29.06-1); however:
  Package nvidia-dkms-545 is not configured yet.
 nvidia-driver-545 depends on nvidia-dkms-545 (>= 545.29.06); however:
  Package nvidia-dkms-545 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package nvidia-driver-545 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                                                                          Process
ing triggers for initramfs-tools (0.140ubuntu13.4) ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-6.8.0-40-generic
Errors were encountered while processing:
 nvidia-dkms-545
 nvidia-driver-545
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)


The tail of /var/lib/dkms/nvidia/545.29.06/build/make.log is
make[2]: *** [/usr/src/linux-headers-6.8.0-40-generic/Makefile:1926: /var/lib/dkms/nvidia/545.29.06/build] Error 2
make[1]: *** [Makefile:240: __sub-make] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-6.8.0-40-generic'
make: *** [Makefile:82: modules] Error 2

Running sudo apt upgrade, now also runs into the same error each time. sudo apt install nvidia-dkms-545 doesn't help as does sudo dpkg-reconfigure nvidia-dkms-545. The latter one complains:
/usr/sbin/dpkg-reconfigure: nvidia-dkms-545 is broken or not fully installed

Lastly, in another question I found checking dkms status:
nvidia/545.29.06: added

and this sudo dkms autoinstall but I get this error:

Kernel preparation unnecessary for this kernel. Skipping...

Building module:
cleaning build area...
unset ARCH; [ ! -h /usr/bin/cc ] && export CC=/usr/bin/gcc; env NV_VERBOSE=1 'make' -j16 NV_EXCLUDE_BUILD_MODULES='' KERNEL_UNAME=6.8.0-40-generic IGNORE_XEN_PRESENCE=1 IGNORE_CC_MISMATCH=1 SYSSRC=/lib/modules/6.8.0-40-generic/build LD=/usr/bin/ld.bfd CONFIG_X86_KERNEL_IBT= modules......(bad exit status: 2)
ERROR: Cannot create report: [Errno 17] File exists: '/var/crash/nvidia-dkms-545.0.crash'
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 6.8.0-40-generic (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/nvidia/545.29.06/build/make.log for more information.

Edits/Additions
Kernel:
uname -a
Linux XXXX 6.8.0-40-generic #40~22.04.3-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Tue Jul 30 17:30:19 UTC 2 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

GCC:
gcc --version
gcc (Ubuntu 11.4.0-1ubuntu1~22.04) 11.4.0
Copyright (C) 2021 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

I am not too familiar with gcc but sudo apt install gcc-12 this says it's already installed.
I've followed the instructions here: Unable to install nvidia-driver-495 and nvidia-dkms-495, but when I choose the nouveau I couldn't even normally boot and had to re-install 535 in safe mode. Before, I did try to install 545 but it failed again.

This question is similar to: Unable to install nvidia-driver-495 and nvidia-dkms-495. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Just now an upgrade caught the 6.8 kernel, lets see if they got the compiler dependency fixed for this.

My suspicion is that it is also related to the compiler but not sure which one it would need. I updated/upgraded and I have still the same issue.

Could it be that the kernel is not compatible with the driver? I did have some unattended upgrades on the 14th (the last day where it worked). Start-Date: 2024-08-14  19:22:56 Commandline: /usr/bin/unattended-upgrade: linux-hwe-6.8-headers-6.8.0-40:amd6

You can see which compiler was used on the kernel: cat /proc/version.  Oddly, this 22.04 6.8 kernel used the gcc-12, unlike the gcc-13 used for 6.8 in 24.04. Seems to have a simple compile error for the Nvidia module. Boot the 6.5 kernel until this gets sorted out -- getting late for me, but my 22.04 had exactly the same issue, can't build the Nvidia 545 module (with the gcc-12?).

The problem seemed to be the linux kernel (6.8.0-40-generic) that I am using, which was installed via unattended upgrades the day before. The problem was also described for Linux Mint (https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=427319). There they suggest installing 550, which is not listed under sudo ubuntu-drivers list but I tried it anyway and it worked via sudo apt install nvidia-driver-550. Unfortunately, this seem to have affect playing Windows games via Steam proton compatibility functionality, which is pretty sad with 535 this works even is with frame drops.
After installing sudo apt install flatpak, Steam & Proton work again but I don't know why and after re-start the dropping frames seem to be gone but some times come back?

Another issue started occurring after this: Ubuntu notices a second "unknown display". Do you perhaps know anything about that?

This was related to the driver not working anymore for me. Once I fixed this, it recognised my screens correctly again.

Thanks! Anyway, the Ubuntu's ecosystem is really a disaster!

It appears that this is a compatibility problem of some kind caused by a Linux kernel update to 6.8.0-40-generic.
I am running Ubuntu 22.04 LTS and was using the closed-source NVIDIA driver version 545 (and CUDA 12.3).
After a reboot, I found that my GPU (NVIDIA RTX 3060) was not being recognized.
The problem seems solved by a driver upgrade to version 555.

Metapackage version 555 worked for me. I installed it from "Software & Updates". Nvidia 4060.
Linux laptop 6.8.0-40-generic #40~22.04.3-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Tue Jul 30 17:30:19 UTC 2 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux



How did you get 555 to show up in Software & Updates?

I also encountered the same problem because the new kernel is not compatible with the existing driver and I need to install a new driver.
If you do not see the new driver version, you can use the following command:
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
sudo apt update

Then this command nvidia-detector will tell you the appropriate version.
After installing from "Software & Updates", if the reboot button does not appear, there may be a problem. In this case, close the "Software & Updates" window first, and then:
sudo apt remove --purge nvidia*
sudo apt autoremove

Then reinstall from "Software & Updates"
